# Magento 2 How to fix Error site has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: api, htaccess, cors

I have Developed a custom API its working fine in Postman, but its not working in another platform.
How to fix this issue.

I tried by updating root `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "index.html" [R=200,E=API:1,PT]
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIf Accept application/json API
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=API
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT" env=API
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization" env=API
</IfModule>
```

Still am getting error as `'http://mysite/' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.`

Where am doing wrong. Can I get Help? Thank you.

Comment: which magento version are you used?

Comment: Thank you @ChandreshChauhan  for responce, I am using magento 2.3

Comment: simplest way to avoid this error disable Magento_Csp module.